# Why Service not injected in Controller with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with a controller and a service injection. In Junit test, it is working all data are added in database and no errors return by my test junit. But when I inject the Service in the Controller, the system return a null object instead instantiation :

My service :

```
package mypackage.services
public interface ExampleService {
public abstract String helloWorld();
}

package mypackage.services;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service("exampleService")
@Scope("singleton")
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {
@Override
public String helloWorld(){
    return "Hello World !";
}
}
```

My Controller:

```
package mypackage.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/planning")
public class PlanningController {

@Autowired
public ExampleService exampleService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final ModelAndView planning(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    exampleService.helloWorld();
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("planning", "tasks", "tasks");
    return mav;
}
}
```

Spring-Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


<!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.services" />                                          
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.controller" />

<!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- View resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <!-- Renders JSON View -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <!-- Resolve the device that originated the web request -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDatasource" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxSize">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minSize">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT * FROM dual</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <resource-ref>
<description>My DataSource Reference</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/myDatasource</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

  <session-config>
   <session-timeout>
     30
   </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

My test :

```
...
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Test
public void testPlanning() {
    LOGGER.debug("Start testPlanning");

    boolean c = applicationContext.containsBean("exampleService");
    System.out.println(c);

    final PlanningController avc = new PlanningController();        
    final Object mav = avc.planning(request);
    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    Assert.assertTrue(mav instanceof ModelAndView);
    ModelAndViewAssert.assertViewName((ModelAndView) mav, "planning");
    final BindingResult result = mock(BindingResult.class);
    when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);
    LOGGER.debug("End testPlanning");
}
```

I inherit from a class for my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-servlet.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})

public abstract class N2WIAppConfigTest {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(PlanningControllerTest.class);

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    // rcarver - setup the jndi context and the datasource
    LOGGER.debug("CALL setUpClass");
    try {
        // Create initial context
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");
        SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = SimpleNamingContextBuilder
                .emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
        // Construct DataSource
        ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        ds.setUser("nemo2");
        ds.setPassword("nemo2");
        builder.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDatasource", ds);
        builder.activate();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.out.println("###################################");
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

}
}
```

I tried in my test load the ApplicationContext and if the service is loaded and it is the case. But in the PlanningController, the service is not injected.

The problem occurs in PlanningController. ExampleService is not injected and don't understand why. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems OK for me, You have `component-scan` and `sterio type annotations` configured correctly, Last, can you try with `@Autowired(required=true)`, at least it gives some more information.

Comment: I tried but no change. I forgot : I receive a NullPointerException on exampleService.heeloWorld() in controller. If I Inject in the test with Autowired, the bean is well injected in test by not in controller. I don't understand

Comment: @JonathanLebrun is there any reason why you use non-versioned xsd for spring-jpa and spring-context and versioned ones for all the rest?

Comment: also try to put spring logs to debug and tell us what you got.

Comment: When you have `@Autowired(required=true)` while building the application context, It should throw an exception on why it is not able to inject the `exampleService`. Try to enable the spring logs and look for the exception

Comment: not exception and even, I have this : 

2012-09-13 13:00:50,751 [AbstractJarVisitor] addElement Filtering: xxxservices.data.ExampleService 
2012-09-13 13:00:50,798 [AbstractJarVisitor] addElement Filtering: xxx.services.data.

It is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

For `@Autowire` to work there are set of things that we need to configure

- `<context:annotation-config />` in context.xml, **You are missing this.**
- `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context` in `<beans ..` tag
- Spring Sterio type annotations like `@Controller, @Component, @Service` etc.

Comment: I added it and the problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in this line:

```
final PlanningController avc = new PlanningController();
```

you are manually creating a bean instance instead of leaving it to spring, so spring has no means to autowire dependencies.

You should either leave bean creation to the container (spring in this case) or set bean properties yourself.

In your case, you can access spring-managed `PlanningController` instance using

```
applicationContext.getBean(PlanningController.class);
```

Comment: I tried and the problem occurs again. If I remove the line in the controller exampleService.helloworld, it is working.